# Can't change value in struct property inside class

Tags: development, vala

```
io = {};
io.wchar = 111111;
debug((string)io.wchar); // (null)
```

So the problem here is that `io.wchar` is still `null`. You can look at the whole class here: https://github.com/stsdc/monitor/blob/dev/src/Managers/Process.vala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Boxing: `IO? io { get; set; default = IO(); }` Note the question mark. (Solution by David Hewitt)
2. Removing get/set: `IO io;` (Solution by thalexander)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are using a cast, try using io.wchar.to_string() [https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/uint64.to_string.html]

Edit:
This worked for me based on your code, casting gave me a segfault.

```
struct Monitor.IO {
    public uint64 wchar;
}

int main (string[] args) {
    Monitor.IO io = {};
    io.wchar = 111111;
    warning (io.wchar.to_string ()); // Struct.vala:9: 111111

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case it showed `0`. And also, please note, that I'm using this inside a class. Maybe there is something wrong with a declaration?

Comment: I would try switching to just defining the property, rather than using get; set; I think there is an issue there but I do not know what.

Comment: Okay, I ran your code, I think you need those two changes and it works for me.

Comment: I think io.wchar = 111111; is getting a copy of io as it is running (io.get().wchar, where get passes a copy not a reference), and then changing the value of wchar of the copy, and then the printing is getting a new copy of io, but the modified version is not being set.